# Custom ipad table view design

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad, cocoa-touch

I want to create an iPad application with look and feel like the following:

[image: Style 2]

[image]

- What is the best standard way to do the left menu, I do not want to subclass any class.
- What is the best way to do the table cell like in the screenshots.

Please advice,

Comment: those are non-standard views, so you won't achieve anything without subclassing. w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for left table [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html), subclass UISplitView **or** just set background color as image, the right table is just a UItableView located in adjusted UIViewController frame.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly won't be able to do that "without subclassing any class". I'm guessing, the app on the screenshots used a split view, a custom table view controller subclass with custom table cells on the left and a more complicated view controller subclass, also with a table view with a custom cell class. And the rest is just a lot of tweaking pixels and background images and gradients.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement left menu using `Grouped TableView`. And table cell on right menu would be `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;`